# Calling a variable or method in the activity class from a class that extends view?

Tags: java, android

I am very new to android and I need help.

I have got a GameActivity class and I set the setContentView to GameView class.
I want to access a variable that is located in GameView class from the GameActivity class.

Is this possible?

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View gameview = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(gameview);

    }

}
```

**And this is my GameView class**

```
public class GameView extends View {

    private static final String TAG = null;     // for log.e

    private Ball ball1;                         // ball1
    private GameContainer gameContainer;        // frame for the game
    private Racket racket;                      // controller
    int viewWidth = 0;                          // width onchange
    int viewHeight = 0;                         // height onchange    
    private Score score;


    // constructor
    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        ball1 = new Ball(Color.GREEN, 24, 10, 2);   // colour, radius,speedx, speedy 
        ball1.setBallLocation(10, 5);   // x, y of ball    
        gameContainer = new GameContainer(Color.GRAY);
        racket = new Racket(Color.BLACK);    
        score = new Score(Color.WHITE);     
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        gameContainer.container(1, 2, 100, 100);
        gameContainer.display(canvas);

        ball1.drawBall(canvas);
        ball1.moveBall(gameContainer);

        // check the ball if it is out display the alert box
        if (ball1.getEndGame()){
            Log.e(TAG, "END of game");
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why not? Access it directly if it is public or create a getter method.

Comment: how can i access it directly?

Answer (score 0):

`Plain Old Java` conventions should work.

Add getter/setter methods for the variables you need access to and use them to get the values.

```
public int getHeight(){
     return viewHeight;
}
```

Would this not work

Answer (score 0):

To access some property directly, first, declare it as public:

```
public int viewWidth = 0;
```

second, just call it:

```
gameview.viewWidth = ...
```